# What is the difference between 2 queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

what is the difference between those 2 queries below?

========The first query==========

```
SELECT 1 AS question_id, COUNT(id) AS answer 
FROM annual_payments 

UNION

SELECT 2 AS question_id, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS answer 
FROM annual_payments 

UNION

SELECT 3 AS question_id, COUNT(id) AS answer 
FROM annual_payments

WHERE STATUS = "paid" AND amount >= 100

UNION

SELECT 4 AS question_id, product AS answer
FROM annual_payments
WHERE status = 'paid'

ORDER BY SUM(amount)

LIMIT 1
```

When I executed this query, I got the error:
Error 1054: Unknown column 'amount' in 'order clause'

==========The second query===========

```
SELECT 1 AS question_id, COUNT(id) AS answer 
FROM annual_payments 

UNION

SELECT 2 AS question_id, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS answer 
FROM annual_payments 

UNION

SELECT 3 AS question_id, COUNT(id) AS answer 
FROM annual_payments
WHERE STATUS = "paid" AND amount >= 100

UNION

SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT 4 AS question_id, product AS answer
 FROM annual_payments
 WHERE status = 'paid'
 ORDER BY amount
 LIMIT 1 ) x
```

=========================

I got the answer with the second query.

The difference between those 2 queries is to use "select *"

Why I got an error with the 1st query? What is the difference between those 2?

Comment: Where is `amount` coming from?

Comment: Probably the 1st query gives an error like: "ERROR 3029 (HY000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY contains aggregate function and applies to the result of a non-aggregated query"    see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810643/mysql-error-error-3029-hy000-expression-1-of-order-by-contains-aggregate-fu)

Comment: Q1: The ORDER BY applies to the whole UNION. There's no SUM(amount) to order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you combine multiple queries with *union*, the column aliases are determined by the *first* query.

An `order by` clause applies to the *entire result set* and must refer to the columns as defined by the first query in the set of unioned queries.

Your second example works because you are not applying `order by` to the unioned results, you are using it within the context of a *derived table* which is fine, it applies to that sub-query only.